# Android Pre-Load Splash Screen

Tags: java, android

Hopefully this isn't a dumb question, but when I initially click on my app, a kind of splash screen first appears for a few seconds with just a title bar indicating the name of the app and nothing else - then the app loads as expected. Is there any way to remove this screen?

Comment: A kind of splash screen, meaning a black screen with the app's title at the top? If yes then make sure your app is fast to load and you aren't doing lengthy operations in the `onCreate` method(like network calls, database operation etc).

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that I'm doing anything too time consuming in there - only setting up the layout and calling a few functions.

Comment: Calling some functions that do what?

Comment: One sets up AdMob ads, another initializes about 10 UI objects, another sets a seek bar listener, and another sets a text view listener - nothing heavy I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system looks into your AndroidManifest.xml to find out what is the theme of the main Activity. If you don't specify it manually, it assumes the application theme, if you don't specify application theme then the default theme is used. The system then creates the "splash screen" solely acoording to the theme.

So if you want to remove it, create a theme that has a transparent background and no ActionBar. And in onCreate() you probably want to change the theme again (or just change the background and show the ActionBar).

But it's better to have some visible "splash screen". Otherwise if you click on the icon, you won't see nothing for 1 - 2 seconds, which is quite weird, almost no app does this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Initializing more resources on

   onCreate()

   may take some time. Try not to overload onCreate() method of Activity.
2. Try not to deep down more than 30 levels inside the xml layout file. which can also take up some      time to initialize .

   setContentView(R.layout.main)

Comment: or try run asynctask in onCreate() :)